# Visual studio does not recognize newly added class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having a weird issue here, i am using vs 2019 and one of my projects refuses to recognize any newly added c# classes, i can not use it anywhere else in the project. This is just an empty class. The new class has no little triangle to the left of it too.

[image: Attached image]

I have tried clean and rebuild this project and did not help, my other projects in the same solution do not have this problem, i am thinking probably i messed up with something in this mvc project but not sure.

this is very frustrating,  any help is very much appreciated.

---

I have fixed this by updating Microsoft.Net.Compilers from 1.0.0 to 3.5.0, and then as its description suggested, use Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.5.0 instead.

I am not sure i completely understand, but seems the problem is that this project uses Microsoft.Net.Compilers instead of MSBuild and the package is out dated.

Comment: Does it only happen with the name "NewlyAddedClass"?

Comment: Is your project based on .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no it happens to any new class added to that project

Comment: @Youssef13 it is .net framkework

Comment: How did you add that class? Don't add it by drag & drop or from the file explorer. You need to add it by right-click on the `Product` folder then add -> new item -> class. Also make sure the namespace is correct **inside** the file

Comment: Can't do much but guess at what's wrong, since you keep everything a secret, but my money is on setting the build type to something other than C# file.

Comment: @Youssef13 thats no i did not drag and drop, what you suggest is exactly what i did, and the name space is correct.

Comment: If you are using git as a VCS then sometimes it helps to stage the file so VS can track it.

Comment: Can you open the csproj file in any text-editor, and paste all its content in the question?

Comment: @Blindy thanks but i dont quite get it the part about build type, and what do you need to know to check into details, i can provide that

Comment: Maybe it want the filename to end in "ViewModel", for example "NewlyAddedClassViewModel.cs". Although that doesn't explain why "ManageProductViewMode.cs" (Mode without an "l") works.

Comment: @Youssef13 it is too big with 4k lines, can you please tell me which part you want to see

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have tried that, actually that is how i found this issue

Comment: @KevinMa Try to search in the file for `ManageProductViewMode` and see if there are any results (and there should be), after that, try to search for `NewlyAddedClass`. If you found results for the `ManageProductViewMode` but not `NewlyAddedClass`, then that's the problem. You may need to update the csproj manually.

Comment: @Youssef13 yes NewlyAddedClass is there

Comment: Can you upload a non-working project to GitHub and leave a link to have a deeper look?

Comment: @Youssef13 I have fixed this, thanks a lot for trying to help

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed this by updating Microsoft.Net.Compilers from 1.0.0 to 3.5.0, and then as its description suggested, use Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.5.0 instead.

I am not sure i completely understand, but seems the problem is that this project uses Microsoft.Net.Compilers instead of MSBuild and the package is out dated.

Comment: I'm on 4.5.2 and the higher versions of the package require 4.7.2

Comment: Thank you, you are my savior. I have been struggling for 2 days without finding a solution until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your screen clip, note the lack of the triangle to expand the member list. This likely means your code isn't being compiled. Right click on the cs file and check properties/build action. Set to "compile" if it's not already.

Answer (score 0):

This solve the issue: update the package Microsoft.Net.Compiler to the latest version, compile and try adding a new class to your project again.

Answer (score -1):

publish the project and classes are recognized

Comment: The person who originally posted this question has already posted the solution to this question.